# How does MAGMI handle updating simple sku's?

Tags: magento, e-commerce, magmi

I am currently using magmi to import products and I am unclear on how the importer works with configurable products and simple product relationships.  Currently you can associate configurble products with simple products by setting  the `simple_skus` filed in the CSV file.

My question is how does magmi handle changes to this field? If there is an SKU removed form the list of simple sku's is the assication removed? Will magmi add an assiocation when there is a new SKU detected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magmi removes all previous associations then applies the new value for the simples that are to be associated with a given configurable.

See [Source Code for configurable plugin](http://sourceforge.net/p/magmi/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/magmi/plugins/base/itemprocessors/configurables/magmi_configurableprocessor.php) , line 62 + (method dolink)